# How to retrieve the stored  database data (i.e data  selected from dropdown ) as  selected data in the dropdown

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

What i have done till now was to store the dropdown selected  data into the database , what i now would like is based on the username typed in the textbox and clicked on search button , the dropdown item to be selected  is  to be the data stored in the database along with a list of values which  user should be able to choose if he wishes .

I just want to know how to replace the text   Select  from here  with the selected data coming from the database as well as allow the user to edit the data as he wants in the dropdown and save it again in the database once he clicks the submit button .

Code While storing data is as follows

```
<?php
if( $_POST['registerbtn']){
$getuser=    mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['user']));
$selected_value = $_POST['selectID'];
if($selected_value != 0){
require("./connect.php");
$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_details WHERE username='$getuser'");
$numrows= mysql_num_rows($query);
if($numrows == 0) { 
mysql_query("INSERT INTO user_details  VALUES (  '','$getuser','$selected_value')");
}
 else
$errormsg = "There is already a user with that username ." ;
mysql_close();
}
else
 $errormsg = "You  must select a linecard";
}
//code to fill dropdown 
require("./connect.php");
$sql = "SELECT select_id, linecard_name FROM selection ". "ORDER BY linecard_name";
$rs = mysql_query($sql);
$options = "<option value = '0'>  Select  from here </option>";
while($rownw = mysql_fetch_array($rs)){
$options .= "<option value = ".$rownw['select_id']." > ".$rownw['linecard_name']. " </option> ";
}
mysql_close() ;

$form = "<form action='./reg.php'  method='post'>
<table>
<tr>
<td>  </td>
<td>  <font color='red'> $errormsg </font> </td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>  Username  </td>
<td>  <input type='text' name='user'  value='$getuser' />  </td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td> Select  Linecard </td>
<td>  <Select name='selectID' > $options  </select> </td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>   </td>
<td>  <input type='submit' name='registerbtn' value='Register' />  </td>
</tr>

</form>";

echo $form;
?>
```

Code while retrieving the data from the database to the dropdown based on username written in textbox is as follows

```
<?php
if( $_POST['savebtn']){
$search = $_POST['search'];
if($search == '' )
{
$errormsg1 = "Enter something in the search box";
}
else
{
require("./connect.php");
$query = mysql_query("SELECT  * FROM user_details  WHERE  username = '$search'");
$numrows= mysql_num_rows($query);
$rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
if($numrows == 1)
{
$getuser = $rows['username'];
$select_id= $rows['linecard_id'];
//selection table where linecard_name is stored along with select_id   for the linecard_name to be displayed 
$query1  = mysql_query("SELECT *  FROM selection  WHERE  select_id = '$select_id' ") ;
$rows1=mysql_fetch_assoc($query1);
$linecard_name= $rows1['linecard_name'];
echo $linecard_name;

$sql = "SELECT select_id, linecard_name FROM selection ". "ORDER BY linecard_name";
$rs = mysql_query($sql);
while($rownw = mysql_fetch_array($rs)){
if( $select_id == $rownw['select_id'])  {
echo $select_id;
$options .= "<option value = ". $select_id ." > " .$linecard_name. " </option> ";
}
}

}
else
$errormsg1 = "Username was Not found";
mysql_close() ;
}
}

?>

<?php
$form ="<form action='ad.php' method='post' id='search' >
<div class='place'>
<tr>
<td>  </td>
<td>  <font color='red' > $errormsg1 </font> </td>
</tr>

<div class='frm2'> <input  type='text'  size='15'  value='$search'  name='search'    /> </div>
<div class='frm3'>      <input type='submit'   name='savebtn'  /> </div>
<div class='clear'> </div>
</div> 
</form>";
echo $form;
?>

<?php
require("./connect.php");
$sql = "SELECT select_id, linecard_name FROM selection "."ORDER BY linecard_name";
$rs = mysql_query($sql);
$options = "<option value = '0'>  Select  from here </option>";
while($rownw = mysql_fetch_array($rs)){
$options .= "<option value = ".$rownw['select_id']." > ".$rownw['linecard_name']. " </option> ";
}
mysql_close() ;
$form = "<form action='./reg.php'  method='post'>
<table>
<tr>
<td>  </td>
<td>  <font color='red'> $errormsg </font> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>  Username  </td>
<td>  <input type='text' name='user'  value='$getuser' />  </td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td> Select  Linecard </td>
<td>  <Select name='selectID' > $options  </select> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>   </td>
<td> <input type='submit' name='savebtn' value='Save' />   </td>
</tr>
</form>";
echo $form;
?>
```

Comment: use your loop inside <Select name='selectID'>

Comment: since form is in php i get error , plz help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store the options into a vairable, let's call it $options and then insert it into your $form variable. Finally you can echo it wherever you want.

```
<?php
require("./connect.php");
$sql = "SELECT select_id, linecard_name FROM selection ". "ORDER BY linecard_name";
$rs = mysql_query($sql);

$options = "<option value= '0' >  Select  from here </option>";
while($rownw = mysql_fetch_array($rs)){
    $options .= "<option value = ".$rownw['select_id']." > ".$rownw['linecard_name']. " </option> ";
} 
mysql_close() ;

$form = "<form action='./reg.php'  method='post'> 
<table>
<tr> 
<td>  </td>
<td>  <font color='red'> $errormsg </font> </td> 
</tr> 

<tr>
<td>  Username  </td>
<td>  <input type='text' name='user' />  </td> 
    </tr> 

<tr>
<td> Select  Linecard </td> 
<td> <Select name='selectID'> $options </select>
</tr> 

<tr>
<td>   </td>
<td> <input type='submit' name='registerbtn' value='Register' />   </td> 
</tr>

</table> 
</form>"; 

echo $form;
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING

Comment: @Sparkle: ok, it should work now, I had a typo when concatenating `$options` inside `$form`.

Comment: if you use double quotes you can put variables **inside** strings: $form = "blabla $options blabla";

Comment: hey @nadirs , can you tell how i can get the selected value on press of register button?

Comment: Reading post variable (according to your code select's name is 'selectID'): `$selected_value = $_POST['selectID'];`

Comment: how to retain the values of a dropdown after submit button is clicked in php , i have got no idea about ajax , please help

Comment: hey @nadirs is it possible to retain the selected  dropdown values when the submit button is clicked

Comment: Didn't `$selected_value = $_POST['selectID'];` work? As a general rule any input-like element (`dropdown` included) you have in your form, on submit will add an entry (whose key is the element's name) in the `$_POST` array in the page you go to after submit. Also it's better not having long discussions in comments. Check this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) (and especially examples it contains).

Comment: Actually @nadirs $selected_value = $_POST['selectID']; works but what i wanted was the selected value in the dropdown to remain selected once the submit button  and  errors are present . I know we are not supposed to have long discussions but i need to know this very badly, plz cooperate ...

Comment: @Sparkle Then add the [property 'selected'](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_selected.asp) to the selected option (choose the option to be selected in the `while` loop with a simple check like `if $_POST['selectID']==$rownw['select_id']))`

Comment: how am i going to assign the selected value to dropdown along with other values also ? plz i need it , what happens  if $_POST['selectID']==$rownw['select_id'])) ?  how am i going to assign the text value ?? , i need to know the selected id also ...

Comment: $options .= "<option value = ".$rownw['select_id'];
 $options .= ($rownw['select_id'] == $select_id )?  " selected = 'selected' " : " " ;
$options .= " > ".$rownw['linecard_name']. " 
  </option>" ;

Answer (score 0):

Please change your code as follows :

```
    <?php
        require("./connect.php");
        $sql = "SELECT select_id, linecard_name FROM selection ". "ORDER BY linecard_name";
        $rs = mysql_query($sql);

        echo "<form action='./reg.php'  method='post'> 
            <table>
              <tr> 
                <td>  </td>
                <td>  <font color='red'> $errormsg </font> </td> 
             </tr>         
             <tr>
                <td>  Username  </td>
                <td>  <input type='text' name='user' />  </td> 
             </tr>         
             <tr>
                <td> Select  Linecard </td> 
             <td>";
     ?>
           <Select name='selectID'>  
              <option value= '0' >  Select  from here </option>  
              <?php

                   while($rownw = mysql_fetch_array($rs)){
                     echo "<option value = ".$rownw['select_id']." > ".$rownw['linecard_name']. " </option> ";
                    }
                ?>
               </select>    
             </tr> 

            <tr>
                <td>   </td>
                <td> <input type='submit' name='registerbtn' value='Register' />   </td> 
            </tr>

        </table> 
     </form>    
 <?php   
    mysql_close() ;
 ?>
```

Comment: can anybody tell me how to get the selected text from the dropdown when register button is clicked and how to make the dropdown not to be refreshed everytime the register button is clicked

Comment: To get the value , you can use $_POST['selectID']. But since in the value attribute of the option tag we are assigning the select_id, that "select_id" will be got in the $_POST['selectID']. To get the selected text, you have to use the select query .

Comment: The drop down will be refreshed only when the page reloads. So if you do not want your page to be reloaded, use ajax.

Comment: Please say something , is it possible to retain the selected  dropdown values when the submit button is clicked

Answer (score 0):

try do this

```
<?php
require("./connect.php");
$sql = "SELECT select_id, linecard_name FROM selection ". "ORDER BY linecard_name";
$rs = mysql_query($sql);
?>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']; ?>" method="POST">
<table>
<tr> 
<td>  </td>
<td>  <font color='red'> $errormsg </font> </td> 
</tr> 

<tr>
<td>  Username  </td>
<td>  <input type='text' name='user' />  </td> 
</tr> 
<?php   while($rownw = mysql_fetch_array($rs)){ ?>
<tr>
<td> Select  Linecard </td> 
<td> <Select name='selectID'> <?php  echo "<option value = ".$rownw['select_id']." > ".$rownw['linecard_name']. " </option> "; ?>  </select>
</tr> 
<?php } //end of while loop ?>
<tr>
<td>   </td>
<td> <input type='submit' name='registerbtn' value='Register' />   </td> 
</tr>

</table> 
</form>;
```

Comment: I think your code will create more select boxes with single options.